# Python - multiple inserts of large text

Tags: python, string, templates

In Python, what's the fastest way (i.e. a single-pass method) to go about inserting two large sets of text, A and B, into another large set of text, C.

Where C is for example:

```
.... ....
<<<A goes here>>>
.... ....
<<<B goes here>>>
.... ....
```

and "...." represents quite a lot of text (i.e. up to 20k).

What's the best way to insert A and B at the appropriate placeholders, where A and B are also not "small" amounts of text (i.e. up to 2k).

My first thought is to do:

```
C.replace("<<<A goes here>>>", A)
C.replace("<<<B goes here>>>", B)
```

however since it's passed through twice, I'd hope there to be a single-pass solution. I've considered a regex but that seems overkill. `string.Template` is an option but the syntax isn't suitable (i.e. `$A` is a placeholder that could have collisions with other text, and '$' wouldn't be suitable escaped elsewhere).

While A and B placeholders occur only once in C, I would like to have a solution that would scale to a larger number of substitutions -- i.e. independent of the number of substitutions; O(n) where n is len(C).

Thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Thank you.

Brian

Comment: Do you have control over `C`?  Could you replace everey `$` in `C` by `$$`?  Is the `%` string interpolation syntax "suitable"?

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I do have control over C, but I'd think a pass to replace `$` with `$$` would be quite slow (relatively), though the `%` string interpolation syntax may be suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [str.find](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) says it returns the index of the first occurrence of the searched-for string, which (to me) implies that it doesn't go through the whole string.  If you know that `"<<<A goes here>>>"` always occurs first,  I'd do:

```
Aflag = "<<<A goes here>>>"
Bflag = "<<<B goes here>>>"
Aidx = C.find(Aflag)
Bidx = C.find(Bflag, Aidx+len(Aflag)+1)

newC = "".join((C[:Aidx], A, C[Aidx+len(Aflag)+1:Bidx], B, C[Bidx+len(Bflag)+1:]))
```

If my assumption is right, this minimizes searching through the string.

Comment: Use `"".join()` for the last line.  `+` for strings creates copies, because strings are immutable.

Comment: @Sven - thanks.  Should I do `"".join( [ ...] )`?  Would Using `( ( ... ) )` create copies also, because it's a tuple?

Comment: A tuple would be slightly faster than a list, but does not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of Python you're using, you can use the `format` function or the `%` operator.  `%` works everywhere, so here's an example:

```
'...\n%s\n...\n%s\n...' % (a, b)
```

That will put the contents of `a` in the first `%s` and `b` in the second.

So, assuming you can change C's placeholders, turn them into `%s`s and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, this may work. Is the performance going to be better? It also occurred to me that you could use named placeholders eg `%(A)` and pass in a dict i.e. `C % {'A': A, 'B': B}`

Comment: @Brian: the only way to know for sure if the performance will be better is to try it.  I don't think it creates more intermediate copies than it needs to, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply any of the string searching algorithms, more specifically KMP which has O(n) time. Since you've assumed you keep A and B separate you could do this in one pass.However, it would probably end up being O(n+k) since you have to replace the string once you've found it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

There's probably a MUCH easier way to do this in Python that I'm not familiar with, but if you've never seen these algorithms they're worth taking a look at.

Comment: Neat references. I'm hoping there's a much easier way to do this in Python, too. ;)

Comment: @Sunandmoon: Python has been using a modified Boyer-Moore method (written in C of course) inside `str.find` etc for some time now. See http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm ...  I don't see the point of trying to improve on that using code written in Python.

Answer (score 1):

the fastest is not the one I thought!
replace is fastest and simpliest

```
s = "\r\n"+("helllo"*100+"\r\n")*100
s2 = (s + "tag1" + s + "tag2" +s  + "tag2" + s + "tag1" + s)*10
t1= ("t1"*100+"\r\n")*100
t2= ("t2"*100+"\r\n")*100

print "size = ",len(s2)

def f1():
 return s2.replace("tag1",t1).replace("tag2",t2)

def f2():
 return "\r\n".join([ x.replace("tag1",t1).replace("tag2",t2) for x in s2.split("\r\n")])

m = {"tag1":t1,"tag2":t2}
def f3():
 p1 = 0
 res= ""
 while(p1 >= 0):
  p2 = s2.find("tag",p1)
  if (p2>=0):
   res+= s2[p1:p2]+m[s2[p2:p2+4]]
   p1 = p2+4
  else :
   res+= s2[p1:]
   p1 = -1
 return res


def g1():
 for i in range(100):
  f1()
def g2():
 for i in range(100):
  f2()

def g3():
 for i in range(100):
  f3()

if ( f1() != f2()):
 print "problem"
if ( f1() != f3()):
 print "problem"


import cProfile
cProfile.run('g1()')
cProfile.run('g2()')
cProfile.run('g3()')
```